# php curl GET request with cookies

Tags: php, curl

I am using the below code to initiate a GET request but I get only "status":403 from the JSON. The JSON needs a cookie to access. So I added the cookie. What mistake am I making here? Why do I get 403 status and can't access JSON?

```
$url = "URL HERE";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
   "Cookie: ci_session=COOKIE HERE",
   "Accept: application/json",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
```

Comment: It seems like it should work, although `CURLOPT_COOKIE` is preferable.

Comment: Are you sure the cookies value you're providing is correct? Maybe it needs other cookie fields, like expiration or a domain?

Comment: @DonR those are parameters for _setting_ cookies. They are not involved when sending the cookie back to the server.